# Add priority words for Tesseract 4.0 LSTM

Tags: dictionary, tesseract, lstm

I'm using Tesseract 4.0 and I'm searching how to add new words with high priority to the Tesseract dictionary. I already tried with Bazaar but only work with oem=0, then I tried to modify the lstm-word-dawg file with combine_tessdata but not work even if my new words were in the list. I will try to train Tesseract with LSTMTraaining but look difficult just to add some words.

So what I have to do? If someone could help me?

Thank for your help

Comment: I think you have to train the data the bazaar thing didn't work for me too so far but i tired it from a binary maybe it works only for building from source (which you will have to do anyway for training the data)